# Inserir dados MySQL com arquivo .txt

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho o seguinte arquivo, um tanto quanto simples:

> new_user.txt

```
JOAO|18|JOAO VITOR BARBOSA|MANDAQUI
ROGERIO|38|ROGERIO JOSE DE BARROS|CAPAO REDONDO
```

Minha tabela no banco foi criada da seguinte forma:

> users

```
create table users (
    primeiro_nome varchar(100),
    idade varchar(2),
    nome varchar(255),
    bairro varchar(255)
);
```

Meu código PHP está da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
require_once('../includes/conecta.php');

$file = fopen('new_user.txt', 'r'); 

while(!feof($file)){
    $data = explode('|', fgets($file)); 
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (primeiro_nome, idade, nome, bairro) VALUES ('".implode("', '", $data)."');";

    $executa = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

    if($executa){
        echo 'DADOS INSERIDOS COM SUCESSO';
    } else {
        echo 'OCORREU UM ERRO!';
    }

}
```

Quando eu dou um `echo` na `$query`, ele me retorna o seguinte:

```
INSERT INTO users (primeiro_nome, idade, nome, bairro) VALUES ('JOAO', '18', 'JOAO VITOR BARBOSA SOUZA', 'MANDAQUI ');INSERT INTO users (primeiro_nome, idade, nome, bairro) VALUES ('ROGERIO', '38', 'ROGERIO JOSE DE BARROS', 'CAPAO REDONDO');
```

Se for levar em consideração, aparentemente as queries estão certas, e no validador que coloquei, ele me retorna o erro e não insere nada na tabela.

A conexão está funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: Faltou você colocar na sua pergunta qual o erro que está aparecendo pra você

Comment: Justamente, ele não me retorna nenhum erro @Sorack

Comment: São 2 inserts no mesmo `mysqli_query()`?

Comment: Sim, não funciona desta forma? @rray

Answer (score 3):

A função [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) excuta apenas uma instrução SQL por vez, o ponto e vírgula faz a delimitação entre as instruções logo isso gera um erro de sintaxe.

Existem duas formas resolver isso a primeira e mais prática é mandar apenas um insert com várias clásulas `VALUES`, essa abordagem garante que todos ou nenhum insert seja feita.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (primeiro_nome, idade, nome, bairro) VALUES "; 
$values = trim("('".implode("','", $data)."'),", ',');
$executa = mysqli_query($conexao, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
```

No lugar de:

```
INSERT INTO users (primeiro_nome, idade, nome, bairro) VALUES ('JOAO', '18', 'JOAO VITOR BARBOSA SOUZA', 'MANDAQUI ');

INSERT INTO users (primeiro_nome, idade, nome, bairro) VALUES ('ROGERIO', '38', 'ROGERIO JOSE DE BARROS', 'CAPAO REDONDO');
```

Será gerada:

```
INSERT INTO users (primeiro_nome, idade, nome, bairro) VALUES
('JOAO', '18', 'JOAO VITOR BARBOSA SOUZA', 'MANDAQUI '),
('ROGERIO', '38', 'ROGERIO JOSE DE BARROS', 'CAPAO REDONDO')
```

A outra é usar função [mysqli_multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: eu utilizando a `mysqli_multi_query()` eu posso simplesmente alternar no meu código?

Comment: @jvbarsou, pode sim (apesar eu não ser muito fã do `multi_query()`) estou editando a resposta com o código.

Comment: @jvbarsou editada a resposta

Comment: apenas alternando para a `mysqli_multi_query` funcionou perfeitamente, pq vc não é mt fã dela? Alias, o segundo metodo, a partir da criação de demais values não funcionou, como esta dentro do while, foi copiada varias vezes a `$query`, entao ao inves de adaptar fui direto ao `mysqli_multi_query` e obtive resultados!

Comment: quando tento subir um arquivo que contenha mais de 500 linhas, ele crasha e n termina o upload. algum motivo aparente?

Comment: @jvbarsou está testando no localhost ou em u externo?

Comment: em um localhost